# Why won't this second item center in the div?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <h1 id="test1">test1</h1><h1 id="test2">test2</h1><h1 id="test3">test3</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#flexbox-container {
      display:inline-flex;
    }
#test1 {
      float:left;
    }
    #test2 {
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      text-align:center;
      align-self:center;
      align-content:center;
    }
    #test3 {
      position:relative;
      left:1000px;
    }
```

Why does test2 not center itself in the flex? I would prefer not to have to set px or margin to get it to centre. I tried all sorts of aligning stuff on it yet it still sticks to the left. I need the three items to be inline, so setting it to flex wouldn't work (though it does center align if I make it flex), PLEASE HELP IVE BEEN TRYING FOR DAYS

https://codepen.io/throwaway123/pen/mdpJJKY

Answer (score 2):

Only this much code is enough. No need for all those styles for separate `h1` tags. You have to give the aligning styles to the parent div.

```css
#flexbox-container {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <h1 id="test1">test1</h1>
  <h1 id="test2">test2</h1>
  <h1 id="test3">test3</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that respects the OP requirements. With the note that having multiple `h1` tags in the same page are a very bad practice.

Comment: thank you. And @CornelRaiu can you please explain why multiple h1 tags on one page is bad? Somebody else also said that using lots of ids is bad which I also don't understand because I use it all the time and it's great

Answer (score 1):

Using IDs for css is bad practice. I'd suggest you to start using class selectors

Anyway, here is solution to your problem :

```
<style>
    #flexbox-container {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: `#flexbox-container` is an ID !?

Answer (score 1):

Basically that isn't how flex works.

You don't want the contents of the second item to be justified within itself, you want the container to have that element centered.

If you scrap all the positioning of the three items you can get flex to do the work for you. There are several ways of telling it how you want the items set out in the line. For example `justify-content: space-between`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

> The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. The first item is flush with the main-start edge, and the last item is flush with the main-end edge.

```css
#flexbox-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <h1 id="test1">test1</h1>
  <h1 id="test2">test2</h1>
  <h1 id="test3">test3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: okay thanks, but that's still specying vw instead of centering it in the middle of the actual document. I floated both elements for a reason

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by 'the actual document'. You can specify what you like as the width - 100% maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the h1 tags centered too you can wrap the h1 tag by a div. Then you can assign the div `text-align: center` CSS Property.

```css
#flexbox-container {
  background: green;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;  
  text-align: center;
}

#flexbox-container div {   
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <div>
    <h1 id="test1">test1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 id="test2">test2</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 id="test3">test3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```